# Ninject Null reference exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject, nullreferenceexception

I am totally new to Ninject and am seeing an exception and dont know what to do. Can someone please help:-

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Object.GetType() +0
   Ninject.Core.Creation.Providers.InjectionProviderBase.GetValueFromInlineArgument(IContext context, ITarget target) in \Ninject\src\Core\Creation\Providers\InjectionProviderBase.cs:139
   Ninject.Core.Creation.Providers.InjectionProviderBase.ResolveConstructorArguments(IContext context, ConstructorInjectionDirective directive) in \Ninject\src\Core\Creation\Providers\InjectionProviderBase.cs:109
   Ninject.Core.Creation.Providers.InjectionProviderBase.CallInjectionConstructor(IContext context) in \Ninject\src\Core\Creation\Providers\InjectionProviderBase.cs:79
   Ninject.Core.Creation.Providers.InjectionProviderBase.Create(IContext context) in \Ninject\src\Core\Creation\Providers\InjectionProviderBase.cs:60
   Ninject.Core.Activation.ActivatorBase.Create(IContext context, Object& instance) in \Ninject\src\Core\Activation\ActivatorBase.cs:114
   Ninject.Core.Behavior.BehaviorBase.CreateInstance(IContext context, Object& instance) in \Ninject\src\Core\Behavior\BehaviorBase.cs:102
   Ninject.Core.Behavior.TransientBehavior.Resolve(IContext context) in \Ninject\src\Core\Behavior\TransientBehavior.cs:55
   Ninject.Core.KernelBase.ResolveInstance(Type service, IContext context, Boolean isEagerActivation) in \Ninject\src\Core\KernelBase.cs:566
   Ninject.Core.KernelBase.Get(Type type, IContext context) in \Ninject\src\Core\KernelBase.cs:278
   Ninject.Core.Resolution.Resolvers.StandardResolver.ResolveInstance(IContext outerContext, IContext innerContext) in \Ninject\src\Core\Resolution\Resolvers\StandardResolver.cs:54
   Ninject.Core.Resolution.Resolvers.ResolverBase.Resolve(IContext outerContext, IContext innerContext) in \Ninject\src\Core\Resolution\Resolvers\ResolverBase.cs:80
   Ninject.Core.Creation.Providers.InjectionProviderBase.ResolveConstructorArguments(IContext context, ConstructorInjectionDirective directive) in \Ninject\src\Core\Creation\Providers\InjectionProviderBase.cs:119
   Ninject.Core.Creation.Providers.InjectionProviderBase.CallInjectionConstructor(IContext context) in \Ninject\src\Core\Creation\Providers\InjectionProviderBase.cs:79
   Ninject.Core.Creation.Providers.InjectionProviderBase.Create(IContext context) in \Ninject\src\Core\Creation\Providers\InjectionProviderBase.cs:60
   Ninject.Core.Activation.ActivatorBase.Create(IContext context, Object& instance) in \Ninject\src\Core\Activation\ActivatorBase.cs:114
   Ninject.Core.Behavior.BehaviorBase.CreateInstance(IContext context, Object& instance) in \Ninject\src\Core\Behavior\BehaviorBase.cs:102
   Ninject.Core.Behavior.TransientBehavior.Resolve(IContext context) in \Ninject\src\Core\Behavior\TransientBehavior.cs:55
   Ninject.Core.KernelBase.ResolveInstance(Type service, IContext context, Boolean isEagerActivation) in \Ninject\src\Core\KernelBase.cs:566
   Ninject.Core.KernelBase.Get(Type type, IContext context) in \Ninject\src\Core\KernelBase.cs:278
   Ninject.Core.Resolution.Resolvers.StandardResolver.ResolveInstance(IContext outerContext, IContext innerContext) in \Ninject\src\Core\Resolution\Resolvers\StandardResolver.cs:54
   Ninject.Core.Resolution.Resolvers.ResolverBase.Resolve(IContext outerContext, IContext innerContext) in \Ninject\src\Core\Resolution\Resolvers\ResolverBase.cs:80
   Ninject.Core.Activation.Strategies.FieldInjectionStrategy.Initialize(IContext context, Object& instance) in \Ninject\src\Core\Activation\Strategies\FieldInjectionStrategy.cs:59
   Ninject.Core.Activation.ActivatorBase.Create(IContext context, Object& instance) in \Ninject\src\Core\Activation\ActivatorBase.cs:130
   Ninject.Core.KernelBase.InjectExistingObject(Object instance) in \Ninject\src\Core\KernelBase.cs:599
   Ninject.Core.KernelBase.Inject(Object instance) in \Ninject\src\Core\KernelBase.cs:288
   Ninject.Framework.Web.KernelContainer.Inject(Object instance) in \Ninject\src\Framework\Web\KernelContainer.cs:69
   Ninject.Framework.Web.UserControlBase.RequestActivation() in \Ninject\src\Framework\Web\UserControlBase.cs:41
   Ninject.Framework.Web.UserControlBase.OnInit(EventArgs e) in \Ninject\src\Framework\Web\UserControlBase.cs:33
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +143
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +391
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +391
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +391
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +391
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +391
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +391
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1477
```

Comment: I think the whole stacktrace is not helpfull enough. You should provide code, how you use ninject.

Comment: Please add more context! How is your NInject kernel is configured? What is the code which is executed when you getting the exception?

Comment: A `NullReferenceException` thrown from within framework code is usually an indication of a bug in that framework, since a framework should never throw a `NullReferenceException` (since NREs are not very helpful in telling what the problem is).

Comment: @Steven, since the exception is originating in `System.Object`, is the "buggy framework" to which you refer the .NET framework?  Also, it is rare for any framework (.NET *or* Ninject) to explicitly "throw a `NullReferenceException`".  Rather, it is due to the ubiqutous problem of dereferencing a null value, which throws the exception implicitly.  This sort of NRE is actually *very* common in any framework since they can happen almost anywhere.

Comment: Normally when you see an exception it is as a consequence of some code that you have written. Where is this code?

Comment: Insufficient information to give a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the stacktrace I can see that you are using some Ninject 1.x.x version. The current release is 2.2.1 and from nuget you can install a release candidate for version 3.0.0. Ninject 1 is not maintained anymore.

I recommend updating either to 2.2.1 or 3.0.0. Otherwise you will have to get the source code from github and debug the problem yourself and provide a pull request to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case I was using the Ninject 3.2.2.0 package from Nuget on Mono and had to roll back to 3.2.0.0, as I found out from [this ticket on the Ninject issue tracker](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/issues/186). It looks like Ninject makes use of a non-published API in .Net by reflection, and this doesn't exist in Mono.